# Gentile Texting a Jew on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Shalom,

I (a gentile) texted my non-observant Jewish friend on Shabbat, having totally forgotten it was Shabbat. He responded before I could unsend. Have I "placed a stumbling block before the blind" and caused one to sin? If so, what can I do (besides never doing it again)? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate.

Comment: Great question. It is not a repost.